# topojson map of italian province into choropleth chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, d3.js, topojson

I've copied a code with a topojson map of italian municipalities (ItalyCom2016WGS84-s1.topojson), and it works with my json data. Now  i want to draw another chart, but with italian provinces.
I download a shapefile from this link:http://www.istat.it/it/files/2011/04/prov2011_g.zip

then I convert it into a topojson file with an online converte. Then I modified all the names, but the second chart doesn't appear. I don't know how to use these libraries, so I don't know what i'm doing wrong.

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>BIOLOGICO - OPERATORI (TOSCANA)</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stile_operatori.css"> <!--collegamento al foglio di stile CSS principale-->
    <style>
        .legenda  { width:60px; height:20px; color: white; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <p id="t">Biologico - Operatori (Toscana) </p>
    </div>
    <div id="l"></div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-scale-chromatic.v1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var fileMap = "ItalyCom2016WGS84-s1.topojson";

        var url = "http://localhost/progetto_tesi/a2.php";

        //  trattamento dei colori
        // scale prese da https://github.com/d3/d3-scale-chromatic
        var color = d3.interpolateRdYlGn;
        // var color = d3.interpolateBlues;
        var scale;

        // Finestra svg
        var width = 1020, height = 960;

        // Scelta della proiezione 
        var projection = d3.geoMercator().scale(3000).translate([-100, 2800]);

        // Funzione di conversione in svg: dipende dalla proiezione scelta  
        var geoPath = d3.geoPath().projection(projection);

        // Creazione dell'elemento svg
        var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)
        .append("g");

        var legenda = d3.select('#l');

        // zoom and pan
        var zoom = d3.zoom()
            .on('zoom', () => {
                svg.attr('transform', d3.event.transform) // updated for d3 v4
            });
        svg.call(zoom);

        var italy;

        var breaks = {
            "Comuni"    : [0, 25, 50, 75, 100, 125, 150, 175],
        };

        /*MAIN*/
        $(document).ready( function() {
            // Definizione dei livelli


            // Caricamento mappa dei comuni
            d3.json(fileMap, function(error, file) {

                // Disegno la mappa dell'Italia
                italy = topojson.feature(file, file.objects.ItalyCom2016WGS84);
                console.log(italy);
                svg.selectAll(".comuni").data(italy.features)
                    .enter()
                    .append("path")
                    .attr("class","comuni")
                    .attr("d",  geoPath)
                    .attr("id",   function(d){return d.properties.PRO_COM;})
                    .attr("fill",  "gray");


                // In base ai parametri disegno le isobande
                drawCoroplethMap();

            }); // d3.json(fileMap, function(error, file) { 


        });

        // $(document).ready( function() {

        function drawCoroplethMap(){
            // Cancellazione della legenda
            legenda.selectAll(".legenda"   ).remove();

            //  trattamento dei colori
            scale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([breaks["Comuni"][0],breaks["Comuni"][7]]).range([1, 0]);

            // creazione legenda
            legenda.selectAll(".legenda").data(breaks["Comuni"])
                .enter()
                .append('div')  
                .attr("class","legenda")
                .attr("style" ,function(d) {return "float:left;background-color:"+color(scale(parseFloat(d)));})
                .text(function(d,i) {return d;});   

            // 1-RECUPERO I PREZZI MEDI COMUNALI
            $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
                svg.selectAll(".comuni").transition()
                    .attr("fill", function(d){
                        var o=data[d.properties.COMUNE.toUpperCase()];
                        if (o !== undefined) colore = color(scale(parseFloat(o)));
                        else { colore = "rgb(128,128,128)";}
                        return colore
                    });
            });
        }

        /*var fileMap2= "prov2011_g.topojson";
        var url2="http://localhost/progetto_tesi/a1.php";
        var color2 = d3.interpolateRdYlGn;
        var scale2;
        var width2 = 1020, height2 = 960;

        // Scelta della proiezione 
        var projection2 = d3.geoMercator().scale(3000).translate([-100, 2800]);

        // Funzione di conversione in svg: dipende dalla proiezione scelta  
        var geoPath2 = d3.geoPath().projection(projection2);

        //Creazione legenda 2
        var l2= d3.select("body").append("div")
        .attr("id", "l2")
        // Creazione dell'elemento svg
        var svg2 = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width2)
        .attr("height", height2)
        .append("g");

        var legenda2 = d3.select('#l2');

        // zoom and pan
        var zoom = d3.zoom()
            .on('zoom', () => {
                svg2.attr('transform', d3.event.transform) // updated for d3 v4
            });
        svg2.call(zoom);

        var italy2;

        var breaks2 = {
            "Provincie"    : [0, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000, 1100],
        };

        /*MAIN*/
        /*$(document).ready( function() {
            // Definizione dei livelli


            // Caricamento mappa dei comuni
            d3.json(fileMap2, function(error, file) {

                // Disegno la mappa dell'Italia
                italy2 = topojson.feature(file, file.objects.prov2011_g);
                console.log(italy2);
                svg2.selectAll(".provincie").data(italy2.features)
                    .enter()
                    .append("path")
                    .attr("class","provincie")
                    .attr("d",  geoPath2)
                    .attr("id",   function(d){return d.properties.NOME_PRO;})
                    .attr("fill",  "gray");


                // In base ai parametri disegno le isobande
                drawCoroplethMap2();

            });
        });

        function drawCoroplethMap2(){
            // Cancellazione della legenda
            legenda2.selectAll(".legenda2"   ).remove();

            //  trattamento dei colori
            scale2 = d3.scaleLinear().domain([breaks2["Provincie"][0],breaks2["Provincie"][11]]).range([1, 0]);

            // creazione legenda
            legenda2.selectAll(".legenda2").data(breaks2["Provincie"])
                .enter()
                .append('div')  
                .attr("class","legenda2")
                .attr("style" ,function(d) {return "float:left;background-color:"+color2(scale2(parseFloat(d)));})
                .text(function(d,i) {return d;});   

            // 1-RECUPERO I PREZZI MEDI COMUNALI
            $.getJSON(url2, function(data) {
                svg2.selectAll(".provincie").transition()
                    .attr("fill", function(d){
                        var o=data[d.properties.NOME_PRO.toUpperCase()];
                        if (o !== undefined) colore2 = color2(scale2(parseFloat(o)));
                        else { colore2 = "rgb(128,128,128)";}
                        return colore2
                    });
            });
        }*/ 
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Could you put a working example at jsfiddle or codepen?

Comment: Yes but i don't know how to put my json data on jsfiddle to let the example work

Comment: what is displayed if you log the `error` in this line: `d3.json(fileMap, function(error, file) {`, does your DOM have elements appended to it, are there other errors in the console? And lastly, did you reproject your data in the online converter?

Comment: I ask because a topojson/geojson export of your shapefile would be quite large (it generates an error for me due to its size), and the data is already projected and therefore cannot be run through a d3 projection.